# json for loop remove duplicates from the output variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to stop repetitions inside the loops because I get duplicated divs 10 times:

```
out = '';
for(var p in outData){
    for(var key in p){
        out += '<div id="'+p+'">'+outData[p]["message"]+' - '+outData[p]["xxx"]+'</div>';
    }
}
$( element ).prepend(out);
```

from a json:

```
outData = {
    "1439335276":{"message":"fg","xxx":"xxx"},
    "1439335668":{"message":"fgx","xxx":"xxx"},
    "1439335675":{"message":"fgxccc","xxx":"xxx"}
}
```

Actually I get correct data, I only need to stop duplicates... what I'm doing wrong?

Actual result:

```
<div id="1439335276">fg - xxx</div>
... x10
<div id="1439335668">fgx - xxx</div>
... x10
<div id="1439335675">fgxccc - xxx</div>
... x10
```

Ideal result:

```
<div id="1439335276">fg - xxx</div>
<div id="1439335668">fgx - xxx</div>
<div id="1439335675">fgxccc - xxx</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your filtering criteria for duplicates. Try `var key in outData[p]` also. SHow expected results

Comment: Do you want to have 3 divs in the end? One for each of the numbers? Then just remove your inner loop, you don't need it.

Comment: @charlietfl if I try: `var key in outData[p]` I get error "p is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra nested loop, remove the inner one

```
for(var p in outData){  
      out += '<div id="'+p+'">'+outData[p]["message"]+' - '+outData[p]["xxx"]+'</div>';    
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h3ygjd3j/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You had one too many loops

```
var out = '';
for(var p in outData){
    out += '<div id="'+p+'">'+outData[p]["message"]+' - '+outData[p]["xxx"]+'</div>';
}
```

Gives:

```
<div id="1439335276">fg - xxx</div>
<div id="1439335668">fgx - xxx</div>
<div id="1439335675">fgxccc - xxx</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is not correct according to JSON or any JS variable name should start with an _ or an alphabet. and you dont need the inner loop, But your call so finally the code is

```
out = '';
for(var p in outData){
    out += '<div id="'+p+'">'+outData[p]["message"]+' - '+outData[p]["xxx"]+'</div>';
}
$( element ).prepend(out);
```